# Changing the nginx user when provisioning a Vagrant box with PuPHPet

Tags: nginx, puppet, puphpet

I'm using Vagrant in order to produce a reusable development server and I'm using Puppet to provision it with a configuration generated with [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/). It's a basic LEMP stack.

Everything is working fine however the nginx user is running as `www-data` and the synced folders are owned by the `vagrant` user. Because of this nginx can't write data to the `/var/www` directory which is causing my Laravel application to throw an exception.

I can manually change the ownership using `chown` however I'd like to just run nginx as the `vagrant` user and have that change in my configuration file.

What changes to the Puppet configuration do I need to make to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

PuPHPet is using the puppetlabs-nginx module which has an nginx::params class in it which in it's turn defines certain nginx config variables including $nx_daemon_user. That said it looks like in your PuPHPet generated manifest you'd want to replace

```
include nginx::params
```

with

```
class {'nginx::params':
  nx_daemon_user => 'vagrant',
}
```